# How to write Chinese fluently?

Tags: writing, handwriting, calligraphy

After learning how to write chinese by directly copying characters from my phone or my computer (digital ones), I noticed that I still can’t decipher the character chinese people are writing.

I know the font is different and I know that practice make it perfect but how would you start to learn how to write ?

Any recommendations, models, etc...?

Ps : here is the difference between my writing and a chinese person for  character 晚 (bottom circled one is mine, the other is from a chinese)
[image: difference in writing]

Comment: Just find a teacher or a tutorial that can teach you about stroke order.

Comment: What’s the relation with stroke order ? I don’t really understand

Comment: e.g. the correct order to write is 丨乛一丿乚, not 丨乛丨一丿乚, or to say, it should be 口+儿, not the rotated 日 + 儿. One basic principle: stroke by stroke. Also, write characters from the left to the right, from the top to the bottom. Generally, the SimSun font, the microsoft Yahei font are those without any confusion. You could try to learn characters in these fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haha, it is difficult even for a native to decipher very cursive or bad handwriting. Basically, when we read, we are only certain about some of the characters and then deduce other characters based on rough shape, context, or other clues.

As for writing, elementary students in low grades are assigned to repeat writing one character for ten or more times in a row. Chinese students are required to write instead of type for most of their tasks, so, after years of writing, people find their accustomed ways to make shortcut. However, most spontaneous writing styles are far from beautiful or even decipherable. In high school, teachers usually make practising handwriting compulsory. The copybook is the most convenient tool for practice. You write on semi transparent paper and emulate standard calligraphy. It's feasible actually. Many students improve quite a lot after several months of practice.

EDIT:

Though my handwriting is not that good, but I believe it is something average in the sense of immaculateness.

[image]

My primary school composition. Posted here as a reference of typical style of newbies.

[image]

Comment: I see, well I guess I will to practice more and ask for 一笔一划写的汉字 before being able to understand

Comment: (`･ω･´)ฅ It's not easy, though. Because “一笔一划写的汉字” is too time consuming... I ll update a photo of my best effort of “一笔一划写的汉字” consuming tolerable time.

Comment: @ClémentJean updated picture. If you have no problem recognizing the characters, then it is enough~

Comment: Wow man thanks for the effort, the problem is that I can’t everything, ahah. But I guess it’s just because I’m not used to it.

Comment: @ClémentJean update 2 haha

Comment: this one I understand ahah